# In quantum mechanics, why position and momentum are related by Fourier Transformation (only)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, fourier-transform

We know that if we take Fourier transform of momentum we go to position space. But why Fourier transform only.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/39442/

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3922/ and http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55674/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question begins and ends with the canonical commutation relationship (CCR), the ubiquitous $[\hat{X},\,\hat{P}]=i\,\hbar\,\mathrm{id}$ where of course $\hat{X}$ and $\hat{P}$ are the position and momentum observables. The CCR alone, as I show in [this answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/80363/26076) implies there is an orthogonal co-ordinate system (which we call position co-ordinates) for the quantum state space wherein:

$$\begin{array}{lcl}\hat{X} f(x) &=& x\,f(x)\\
\hat{P} f(x) &=& -i\,\hbar\,\mathrm{d}_x\,f(x)\end{array}$$

This being so, if we want to transform to a co-ordinate system wherein the momentum, and thus the derivative $\mathrm{d}_x$ becomes a multiplication operator, then the basis states (strictly speaking, as tempered distributions as [discussed here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90261/26076)) have to be the eigenvectors of the derivative operator. These are, of course, distributions of the form $e^{i\,k\,x}$, and to find their relative weights in a quantum state, *i.e.* superposition, we decompose that superposition with the Fourier transform. So there you are!